# UseQuery with variables:{} param from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to run a useQuery hook with variable:{} parameter but the data I am passing into variables is coming from a useEffect Hook.

I know I am unable to pass in the useQuery into useEffect so I have been passing in the data from useEffect into a state variable and then passing that into the useQuery.

This actually works okay and does not crash the app but it does hit the error hook about 3 times before it actually does work

Here is how my code looks

```
 const router = useRouter();

 const { id } = router.query;

 const [user, setUser] = useState({});

 const [profileTypeA, setProfileTypeA] = useState(false);

  let userData

useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser() {
      if (!router.isReady) return;
      const userDb = await getUserFromDb(id);
      if (userDb === undefined) {
        return <Error statusCode={404} />;
      } else {
        setUser(userDb?.data?.payload);
        if (userDb.data.payload.type === 'A') setProfileTypeA(true);

      }
    }
    getUser();
    return () => {
      consola.success('Cleanup profile page');
    };
  }, [router.isReady]);

  if (profileTypeA) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY_FOR_USER_TYPE_A, {
      variables: { id: user?.userId },
    });
    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return <Error statusCode={404} />;
    userData = data?.moreData;
  }
```

My problem is with the variables is this the best way to pass the dynamic data to variables?

I realize that is a flaw to be honest I was going to deal with that later (which maybe I am underestimating). But even if I take the useQuery out of the if block then the error is still there.

My logic is intended as follows:

1. In useEffect

   1. get {id} from the router
   2. trigger getUserFromId(id) with that id
   3. setUser() with db response
2. Run the query

   1. get user from state and pass it into variables:{} for query
   2. run the query

I think that my problem is that the useEffect is running after my useQuery so the user i am trying to get from the useEffect is still empty but I am not sure how and where else I can run all the logic I have in my useEffect to get the data i need to pass into the variables:{}

Thank you

Comment: You are breaking the rules of hooks by calling `useQuery` conditionally on `profileTypeA`. It's a bit unclear to me though what you're trying to do here. Can you "walk" us through the logic and what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: hey @DrewReese thanks for responding! I edited my original post let me know if that's clearer now. thanks again

Comment: Yes, that is helpful, but we're still missing a bit of context. What is `userData` in the `if (profileTypeA)` block? Can you also provide us a more complete and comprehensive example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ya good catch. The userData is just a generic variable I left up top its not a useState hook. (just added it to the original post)